# How do I add a subheading to a view?

Tags: views, 8

I have created a custom content type to upload documents in English and French.Currently using views module I am listing the uploaded files based on date of creation,now I have to categorize the files on list view based on the  language(en/fr).

**Existing view**

Docs

- French1
- French2
- English1
- French3

I have to  separate the listing based on document language and display it as two blocks with different title.

**Required view**

French Docs

- French1
- French2
- French3

English Docs

- English1
- English2
- English3

**Edit**

I have achieved this using View module itself.

- First I have created the option to choose uploaded language and sort
  order in the content type.
- Created a view to display French Docs in the required order.
- Included the view block for English in the Footer section of views for French like : Global: View area (Global: View area)

Answer (score 1):

Well, drupal can't know the language used in uploaded files unless the user or an admin specifies so.

A simple way to achieve what you want is to-

1) Have a checkbox field holding the values "English or French" in your custom content-type.

2) And then you can create two views, one holding **"English docs (filter:Checkbox=English)"** and the other **"French docs (filter:Checkbox=French)"**.

3) Embed one view into the other as a view field using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

> views_field_view allows you to embed one view into another view and pass arguments along.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Instead of using Views Field View module I have included the view block for English in the Footer section of views for French like : Global: View area (Global: View area)