# How to display views titles by categories

Tags: views

I have a content type which has **category** field.

I added few nodes. Each node has a value from **category**.

I would like to display a views block which should display titles grouped by category. That means:

Category 1

title

title

title

Category 2

title

title

title

**I created a views block:**

Format: Unformatted list

Fields: Title

Now, I have list of titles. I am not sure how I can add category(non linked) before the relevant titles?

Comment: I suppose similar questions have been asked before here (so a comment instead of an answer). Add your category as a field, and suppress it from showing. Then in the format settings (left top) choose a grouping field. That will give what you need.

Comment: Please refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237954/how-do-i-add-a-subheading-to-a-view

Answer (score 1):

You can group content based on the field. Click the format settings in View,

[image]

select the field here and group the content

**NOTE:** Grouping field should be added in the field area and then field will be shown in the grouping select list.